# how to Parse Map value Data in android

Tags: java, android

```
   Map<String, String> map =dataSnapshot.getValue(Map.class);

                String MR_ID = map.get("MR_ID");
                String JOB_TITLE = map.get("JOB_TITLE");
                String JOB_TYPE = map.get("JOB_TYPE");
                String Delv_ADDR=map.get("Delv_ADDR");
```

> DataSnapshot { key = platformdb, value =
>   {MR_RELATIONS={CUSTOMERS={ORDERS={INVENTORY=, Delv_ADDR=D-103
>   LaxmiNagar New Delhi, ORDER_ID=}}}, MR_SCHEDULE={MR_ID=, JOB_TITLE=,
>   GEO_LINK=, JOB_TYPE={TSP={TSP_ADDR=, TSP_ID=, GEO_LINK=, TSP_NAME=},
>   SCC={SCC_ID=, SCC_ADDR=, GEO_LINK=, SCC_NAME=}, CUSTOMER={GEO_LINK=,
>   CUST_NAME=, CUST_ID=, CUST_ADDR=}}, JOB_ID=, TRANS_SRC=, TRANS_DEST=},
>   MR_POOL={FREE_MR=, BUSY_MR={77889992222={IS_BUSY=false,
>   GEO_LINK=8yyttrd}}}} }

This is my Data i am getting in map i want to Parse and and get value of **Delv_ADDR** But i am unable to get i am getting Null value please suggest me how to get data of that

Answer (score 1):

From the attached input it seems that there is only one entry in the map with key `platformdb` and value as `MR_RELATIONS=...`.

If you are doing `String MR_ID = map.get("MR_ID");` then it will probably return you `null` as there is no entry in the map with key `MR_ID`.

What you should be doing instead is retrieve the value against the key by doing the following:

```
String response = map.get("platformdb");
```

And then parse this response String to extract the desired values.

Since, response does not seems to be JSON you  can try using native String functions.

For example, to extract `MR_ID` from response you can do the following:

```
String response = map.get("platformdb");
String MR_ID = response.substring(response.indexOf("MR_ID=") + 6,
                                  response.indexOf("MR_ID=") + response.indexOf(","));
String Delv_ADDR = response.substring(response.indexOf("Delv_ADDR=") + 10,
                                  response.indexOf("Delv_ADDR=") + response.indexOf(","));
```

Comment: its not JSON Data because = its not :

Comment: @ResearchDevelopment Yes, you are right. You can try using native functions. Have a look at the updated answer.